# Stumped by how my code is modifying something that shouldn't be modified

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write some very simple code, and essentially what I am doing is reading in two columns of time-series data (that correspond to slightly different time-bins), and looping through different % weights of the second column of data with itself in consecutive time bins. However, when I run this loop, for some reason the original dataframe (specifically, df['EST'] is somehow being changed by this line:

```
X_new[j-1]=Wt*X_temp[j-1]+(1-Wt)*X_temp[j]
```

I narrowed it down to this line of code, because when I eliminate it, it no longer makes changes to the initial dataframe. I don't understand how this line could be changing the original dataframe.

My complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

import csv
import os
os.chdir("C://Users/XXX")
raw_data = open('correlation test.csv')
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv(raw_data)

Y=df['%<30'][1:].reshape(-1,1)
X_new=df['EST'][1:].reshape(-1,1)

X_temp=df['EST'][1:].reshape(-1,1)

Wt=0
Best_Wt=Wt
Best_Score=1
for i in range(1,100):
    for j in range(1,df.shape[0]-1):
        X_new[j-1]=Wt*X_temp[j-1]+(1-Wt)*X_temp[j]
        asdf=0
    RR=LinearRegression()
    RR.fit(X_new,Y)
    New_Score=np.mean(np.abs((RR.predict(X_new)-Y)))
    if New_Score<Best_Score:
        Best_Score=New_Score
        Best_Wt=Wt
        print('New Best Score:',Best_Score)
        print('New Best Weight:',Best_Wt)
    Wt=Wt+0.01
```

The file that it pulls from is two columns of percentages, the first column is labeled '%<30' and the second column is labeled 'EST'
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This means that `X_new` is a view of `df['EST']`, not a copy. To get a copy, do: `X_new=df['EST'][1:].copy(deep=True).reshape(-1,1)`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.